# How to correlate timestamps and LFP data

Tags: timestamp

Hi I have collected LFP data from animals and it is stored as Data.streams.Wave.data which is 1X307904 (sampling rate is 1000) I have collected timestamps for the same data as Data.epocs.Valu.data 15143X1 (sampling rate is 50)

How I could compare the timestamps with corresponding LFPs in **MATLAB**?

Thanks!